Debugging a Haar wavelet transform in the Fourier domain
I'm trying to get a minimum-viable prototype going for a project on sensor fault detection using a scale-zero Haar wavelet (frequency-domain locality is not important). After some Googling, I managed to find several definitions (all without sources or derivations), e.g. the one of Y. Sheng, 2000 (p. 20, eq. 10.2.12),
$$
H(\omega) = \exp\left(- \frac{\omega}{2}\,j\right) \cdot\frac{4\,j}{\omega} \cdot\left(1-\cos\frac{\omega}{2 }\right)\qquad\omega\geq0.
$$
Now I'm trying to obtain this result from a DFT-transformed signal to see whether my setup is correct. I figured I'd use an rfft since the input signal will also be real in production
Using the following code, however,
import numpy as np
import scipy.fft as scp_fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_periods: int = 8
n_samples: int = 250

def filter_H(omega: np.array) -> np.array:
    return np.divide(
        4j * np.exp(-.5j*omega) * (1 - np.cos(.5*omega)), omega, where = omega != 0)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)

omega = np.linspace(0, n_periods * 2*np.pi, n_samples // 2 + 1)

# Directly in the Fourier domain using Y. Sheng 2000 eq. (10.2.12)
res: np.array = filter_H(omega)
ax[0].plot(omega, res.real)
ax[0].plot(omega, res.imag)

# Using a transform
filter_h = np.zeros(n_samples)
filter_h[:n_periods] = 1
filter_h[n_periods:2*n_periods] = -1
filter_h /= 2*n_periods
filter_ft_H = scp_fft.rfft(filter_h, n = n_samples)
ax[1].plot(omega, filter_ft_H.real)
ax[1].plot(omega, filter_ft_H.imag)

plt.show()

I obtain considerably different plots:

I've spent the better part of two days on this already. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

The results are different because they represent different things. The first formula is the continuous Fourier transform of the continuous Haar wavelet (apart from a scaling factor). The second result is the discrete Fourier transform of a discretized Haar wavelet. Sampling the Haar wavelet results in aliasing, that's why the two results are different. You can reduce the aliasing error by using more sample points, but the error will never become zero.
EDIT:
Let's compare the analytical formulas obtained from the continuous-time Fourier transform (CTFT) of the Haar wavelet and from the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of the discretized Haar wavelet. The Haar wavelet is defined by
$$h(t)=\begin{cases}1,&0<t<\frac12\\-1,&\frac12<t<1\\0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
For $\omega\neq 0$, the CTFT of $h(t)$ is
$$H(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt=2je^{-j\omega/2}\frac{1-\cos(\omega/2)}{\omega}\tag{2}$$
For $\omega=0$ we have $H(0)=0$.
Let's choose an even number $N$ of discrete samples of the Haar wavelet:
$$h[n]=\begin{cases}1,&0\le n< N/2\\-1,&N/2\le n< N\\0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{3}$$
The length $L$ ($L\ge N$) DFT of $h[n]$ is
$$H[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]e^{-j2\pi nk/L}\tag{4}$$
The DFT $H[k]$ scaled by $1/N$ is an approximation of the CTFT $H(\omega)$ evaluated at the discrete frequencies $\omega_k=2\pi k N/L$.
For $k=0$ we have $H[0]=0$. For $k\neq 0$ we obtain the following expression:
$$H[k]=je^{-j(\omega_k/2-\pi k/L)}\frac{1-\cos(\omega_k/2)}{\sin(\omega_k/2N)}\tag{5}$$
Comparing $(2)$ to $(5)$, we see that for $N\to\infty$ (which implies $L\to\infty$ because we required $L\ge N$), $H[k]/N$ approaches $H(\omega_k)$.
The figures below show the CTFT and its DFT approximation for $N=16$ and $N=64$, respectively. The DFT length was chosen as $L=1024$ in both cases.



Thank you and Hilmar very much. My apologies for the basic questions, I'm not well-versed in DSP. Is it possible to obtain a closed-form solution for what a discrete-time Fourier transform of a discretized Haar wavelet would look like, i.e. an equation for the bottom plot?

@user169291: Please see my edited answer.

Hey Matt, I have no words. I've stumbled upon a similar question yesterday (I'm mentioning this so you know mine wasn't motivated by laziness) and had been working on figuring out a derivation since, as that one has no references either. Thank you for making my week-end!

@user169291: You should try to derive these results yourself. It's not terribly hard, and you don't need to rely on results floating around the internet.

I always make it a point not to use any code or math I don't (think I) understand completely; that's why I was doing this in the first place as opposed to pip install-ing some black-box. Now, however, I have certainty as to what the problem is. Of course I'll try to derive it myself. Thank you again. I've accepted your answer as you've remarked

Just adding to Matt's answer. You can see the aliasing in the time domain wave forms. The Haar wavelet has infinite bandwidth so you can't sample it without aliasing.

